# Monohybrid Recombinant Frequency? (three point Gene Linkage)

Tags: genetics, homework, population-genetics

I am curious to know if it is completely impossible calculate recombinant frequency for monohybrids ( three point link, gene map etc.)

Here is an example:

Marker 1

1. xx= 25
2. xy=100
3. yy= 20

Marker 2

1. xx=30
2. yx= 89
3. yy= 20

Marker 3

1. xx= 100
2. yx=50
3. yy= 100

This is what I think it would be like for x:x Marker 1 to 3

grand total = 534

So from Marker 1 to Marker 2 it would be 25+30/534 = 0.1029

Marker 2 to Marker 3 : 30 +100/534= 0.2429

Marker 1 to Marker 3: 125/534= 0.2340

Am I on the right track --- if not can you please show how it would be done for this example?

Comment: Can you please clarify what `xx`, `xy` and `yy` are as well as the genotypes of the parents? What are the two loci and the alleles at each locus?

Comment: xx and yy are the parents (genotype), the alleles are either x or y

Comment: How about the other locus, then? You can only talk about recombinants if you consider at least 2 loci.

Comment: This information is from a sample SNP call data indicating the to total calls for those genotypes. That's all the information I have is there no way to calculate RF ?

Comment: No, you can't calculate a recombination rate between two loci with only information about a single locus. If your question is a homework question, please use the homework tag

Comment: Oh I understand what you are saying ( this is not hw , it a "what if" question) Let give some more hypothetical information--- the information above is for Marker 1 I I will a bit more to my question

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Can you please show your attempt? You can have a look at this [Khan Academy article](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/classical-genetics/chromosomal-basis-of-genetics/a/linkage-mapping) that very nicely explain how to compute genetic distances.

Comment: Hi -- My attempt above for x:x